# Why a call to a celery task block forever?

Tags: django, python-3.x, redis, celery

I follow the tutorial at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cobros.settings')

app = Celery('cobros')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

# Settings
CELERY_APP="cobros"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

and call my first job:

```
@task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info("Sum ", x, y)
    return x + y

def syncClientAsync():
    baseDir = getBaseDir(str(cobrador.id))
    print("Delay...")
    return add.delay(4, 4) #No work
    return add.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=1) #No work
```

When I run the code python get stuck/blocked forever. Redis and Celery are running and not report any error or problem.